# How is the strength of password evaluated?

Tags: passwords

Recently I came across `howsecureismypassword.net`. The site evaluates how many year a computer would take to crack the given password  but they don't provide the criteria on which they evaluate no. of years

So the questions arises:

1. Is there any standard algorithm for such?
2. Ain't the number of depends on computing power available at hand?
3. Or is there any lower limit which is same for any computation power ?

Comment: 1) Not aware of such an algorithm. I would assume that this has something to do with brute-force and the 'space' of values that needs to be tried to crack the password entered.   2) Absolutely, and from the software used for cracking, and from the conditions of checking whether the password candidate is indeed the correct password (think of login attempts in Linux - it will not let you try 1000 paswords per second).    3) No, I don't see how this can be possible - what if your computational power is restricted by the power of a calculator produced in 1970s...

Comment: Anyway, the site is promoting some free password manager and should not be taken seriously.

Comment: @A.Toumantsev Just a reminder: ***`Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments.`***